# How do I reset google login configuration once I have set it for my meteor app?

Tags: meteor

I am learning meteor and have created a new app and installed accounts-core, accounts-google and accounts-ui.  This worked as expected and prompted me to configure the google integration.  After I configured it, though, I realized I used an incorrect url and changed it in the Google API.  How do I make this change take effect in the meteor side?  In other words, how do I get back to the meteor google configuration page where I enter the client id and secret?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, add the service configuration package:

```
meteor add service-configuration
```

Then, in your app in the system folder (create it if you don't have one) add a file called service.js and in there add:

```js
// first, remove configuration entry in case service is already configured
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: "google"
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
  service: "google",
  clientId: "123456789",
  loginStyle: "popup",
  secret: "8j4ldfjSECRET-HEREalkjf8slk"
});
```

**Further Reading**:
[Meteor Docs - Login With External Service](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice)

Comment: You may wanna use `ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert` rather than delete/insert.

Answer (score 20):

This is just a light revision in snize's answer, but this worked for me:

```
$ meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3002/meteor
> db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.remove({"service":"google"})
```

Comment: For deployed projects you can also edit the entry with your new client_id and secret, rather than resetting it.

Answer (score 3):

How about this.

Clearing only account configuration.I have tried in my project.

[meteor mongo](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteormongo)

```
$ meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3002/meteor
> show collections
meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration
posts
system.indexes
users
> db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration
meteor.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration
> db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.find()
{ "service" : "twitter", "consumerKey" : "MYconsumerKey", "secret" : "MYsecret", "_id" : "MYid" }
>
> db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.remove()
```

Clearing all data in your project.

```
$ meteor reset -h
Usage: meteor reset

Reset the current project to a fresh state. Removes all local
data and kills any running meteor development servers.
```

Comment: Seems like a 'nuclear option'.  Any way to refresh just the google api setting, without _deleting all data in the app_?

Answer (score 1):

A `meteor reset` will bring everything back to 0, use it wisely.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this on your production server, where you don't have `meteor` but you can run `mongo` from the shell, then the process is pretty similar:

```
$ mongo
...
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
...
> show dbs
foo           0.078GB
bar           0.078GB
my_meteor_db  0.078GB
> use my_meteor_db
switched to my_meteor_db
> show collections
...
> db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.find()
...
> db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.remove({service:"google"})
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
> exit
bye
$
```