# How do I REconfigure Meteor's accounts-facebook, or where is Meteor's Facebook configuration?

Tags: facebook, meteor

Meteor's `accounts-facebook` package was very easy to set up. To input the Facebook app ID and secret token, I loaded my meteor web app in a browser, and clicked on the login button, and then clicked 'Configure Facebook', which asked me for configuration values such as the app ID and secret token.

Now I want to change those and can't figure out where they're stored. I don't see them in any file in my meteor app's directory or subdirectories, nor are they in the database anywhere.

Comment: Pretty much in the same place as the [Google login configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098307/how-do-i-reset-google-login-configuration-once-i-have-set-it-for-my-meteor-app) - funny how that question was asked just a few days before this one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The configuration data is stored in mongodb.

If you load up

```
meteor mongo
```

Then use `db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.find()` you should see your config data

You can update it too! If you got back

```
{ "service" : "x", "appId" : "x", "secret" : "x", "_id" : "abc" }`
```

Within the same mongo shell:

```
db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.update({_id:'abc'},
    {$set:{"appId" : <new app id>, "secret" : <new secret>}});
```

(Using the `_id` field from the service configuration that you want to edit.

Within Meteor you can use this instead:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update({
    service:"facebook"
}, {
    $set: {
        <new params>
    }
});
```

Note to do this within meteor you need to add this package in with :

```
meteor add service-configuration
```

Comment: Doh. Looks like I didn't refresh the db's collections somehow? (I'm using Robomongo GUI). They're there as you describe. Thanks!

Comment: Although it's valuable to know where your data is stored, I find the answer below much better since it uses the official API which is easily scripted from the server code.

Comment: @oligofren Thanks, i've also updated my answer, since the collection has been renamed again to `ServiceConfiguration`

Answer (score 19):

To elaborate on Kristoffer's answer, here is how to configure an app at runtime

**/server/boot.js**

```
configureFacebook = function(config) {
    // first, remove configuration entry in case service is already configured
    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
        service: "facebook"
    });

   ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
        service: "facebook",
        appId: config.clientId,
        secret: config.secret
    });
};

// set the settings object with meteor --settings private/settings-local.json
var facebookConfig = Meteor.settings.facebook;
if(facebookConfig) {
    console.log('Got settings for facebook', facebookConfig)
    configureFacebook(facebookConfig);
}
```

This is used in conjunction with some settings files that are used locally and for production:

**/private/local-settings.json**

```
{
    "facebook" : {
        "clientId": "330foobar",
        "secret": "52e1e247a5a1234klasdf087vasdff07"
    }
}
```

To develop locally I just do `meteor --settings private/local-settings.json` and to deploy the production settings for facebook to the production server I do `meteor deploy --settings private/prod-settings.json`.

Comment: @ShankarRegmi seems legit, but I haven't used Meteor in a year, so I can't vouch for it. thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: P.S. If it works, @ShankarRegmi, just edit my answer and improve it.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
  service: "facebook",
  appId: "1292962797",
  secret: "75a730b58f5691de5522789070c319bc"
});
```

Found here: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice

Comment: I saw that, thanks (btw I don't know where that code would go if I'm using the {{loginButtons}} `handlebars` helper). But I want to know where the configuration file is and just change it there.

Comment: Why not do it the supported/documented way? That code would go on the server, somewhere between if (Meteor.isServer) { //HERE } or in a a .js file in a server/ directory.

Comment: This solution needs updating to reflect current Meteor. Run: 'meteor add service-configuration' And the function is now: 'ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert' and it's appID instead of "clientId'

Comment: @LloydDewolf: thanks for letting me now! Spent too much time scratching my head :) I updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

This will simply delete all services at startup and reinsert them based upon your settings.json (meteor --settings settings.json)
Coffee-script equivalent:

```
@privateSettings = Meteor.settings.private

for s in privateSettings.services
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove service: s.service
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert s
```

Settings stored in settings.json:

```
{
  "private": {
    "services": [{
        "service": "google",
        "clientId": "yourappid.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "secret": "yoursecret"
    },{ 
        "service": "twitter",
        "consumerKey": "yourconsumerkey",
        "secret": "yoursecret"
    },{
        "service": "facebook",
        "appId": "yourappid",
        "secret": "yoursecret"
    }],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have much data in your application, just run:

```
meteor reset
```

This will wipe out all of Mongo's data for the app.

Answer (score 1):

**[NOTE: for Meteor >= 1.2.2]**

The official Meteor documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice) explains how to do it.

Add the `service-configuration` package (otherwise you can't use `ServiceConfiguration`):

```
$ meteor add service-configuration
```

Then you can put this in `Meteor.startup`:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  // Set Facebook app configurations
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({ 
    service: "facebook" 
  }, {
    $set: {
      appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
      secret: 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'
    }
  });

  return;
});
```

---

**Externalize Facebook configurations in settings.json**

Perhaps the final solution is to put Facebook app's configurations in a setting file

```
/settings.json
```

Like this:

```
{
  "facebook" : {
    "appId": "APP_ID",
    "secret": "APP_SECRET"
  }
}
```

Then you have to start your Meteor application with

```
$ meteor --settings settings.json
```

in order to load the settings file.

Finally you can load Facebook configurations inside `Meteor.startup` from the settings file:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  // Load and set Facebook app configurations
  var facebookConfig = Meteor.settings.facebook;
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({ 
    service: "facebook" 
  }, {
    $set: {
      appId: facebookConfig.appId,
      secret: facebookConfig.secret
    }
  });

  return;
});
```