# Meteor facebook login. Doesn't work after linking new Domain name

Tags: facebook, authentication, dns, meteor

my Facebook Login worked for everything before, from locahost to .meteor.com, and also when I deployed it to modulus (.onmodulus.net). I had to reconfigure the keys each time of course. But now I bought a domain name at Gandi.net (jamscope.in) So now when I go to jamscope.in it opens the .onmodulus.net site. Now the facebook login no longer works and gives me no error either. I tried reconfiguring the facebook bit to both jamscope.in, and then back to http://jamscope-21300.onmodulus.net/, but neither works. I don't know what to do since I have no experience with linking domain names. What can I do?

CLARIFY:

I deployed my site on .onmodulus.net, and then bought a new domain name (jamscope.in) for it, now when I login at jamscope.in, the facebook popup is blank, and the URL of that popup is (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=544143532381792&redirect_uri=http://jamscope-21300.onmodulus.net/_oauth/facebook?close&display=popup&scope=email&state=8syVowrx8t1R8srHiXG6T_TjF3MyN9sbFKO_9HAqkNR)

It still refers to the old domain name>

I tried reconfiguring the facebook developer part but none if it worked

Comment: oh, you are saying in your meteor app, you have no error when you try and login?

Comment: I'm saying there were no errors, until I linked my app to a custom domain name taht I bought. Then it has errors. The facebook popup window still refers to the old domain name, not the custom one, I think it may be related to taht

Comment: sounds like you haven't recofigured your facebook appid/key on the meteor side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140483/how-do-i-reconfigure-meteors-accounts-facebook-or-where-is-meteors-facebook-c

Comment: Hi Keith, I have reconfigured it, both from developer.facebook and mongoDB. The fact is, it was already configured to my old ugly URL (jamscope-21300.onmodulus.net) which worked, but my new URL (jamscope.in) simply points to that old one, it is NOT a new application. I tried changing the website URLs on developer.facebook but I get teh same result: When I sign in on jamscope.in, the facebook popup tries to redirect to the old ugly URL (jamscope-21300.onmodulus.net) but it doesnt work: (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=...&redirect_uri=http://jamscope-21300.onmodulus.net/...)

Comment: looks like something in the meteor app, it gives facebook the redirect uri

Comment: yes I'm looking at how I can set the redirect URI myself, not sure where to look

Comment: changed my answer,  I think you need to set the enviroment variable, ROOT_URL  to your domain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set meteors  ROOT_URL

which comes from the environment variable of the same name

Comment: It worked! I changed the environmental variable ROOT_URL on Modulus to my new Domain and it worked. But now my Googlemaps API functionality is broken I don't know why :'(